# Perl print out all subs arguments at every call at runtime

Tags: perl

I'm looking for way to debug print each subroutine call from the namespace `Myapp::*` (e.g. without dumping the CPAN modules), but **without the need edit every `.pm` file manually** for to inserting some module or print statement.

I just learning (better to say: trying to understand) the `package DB`, what allows me tracing the execution (using the shebang `#!/usr/bin/perl -d:Mytrace`)

```
package DB;
use 5.010;

sub DB {
    my( $package, $file, $line ) = caller;
    my $code = \@{"::_<$file"};
    print STDERR "--> $file $line $code->[$line]";
}

#sub sub {
#    print STDERR "$sub\n";
#    &$sub;
#}

1;
```

and looking for a way how to use the `sub` call to print the actual arguments of the called `sub` from the namespace of `Myapp::*`.

Or is here some easier (common) method to

- combine the execution line-tracer `DB::DB`
- with the Dump of the each subroutine call arguments (and its return values, if possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it counts as "easier" in any sane meaning of the word, but you *can* walk the symbol table and wrap all functions in code that prints their arguments and return values. Here's an example of how it might be done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.14.2;
use warnings;

package Foo;

sub first {
    my ( $m, $n ) = @_;

    return $m+$n;
}

sub second {
    my ( $m, $n ) = @_;

    return $m*$n;
}

package main;

no warnings 'redefine';

for my $k (keys %{$::{'Foo::'}}) {
    my $orig = *{$::{'Foo::'}{$k}}{CODE};
    $::{'Foo::'}{$k} = sub {
        say "Args: @_";
        unless (wantarray) {
            my $r = $orig->(@_);
            say "Scalar return: $r";
            return $r;
        }
        else {
            my @r = $orig->(@_);
            say "List return: @r";
            return @r
        }
    }
}

say Foo::first(2,3);
say Foo::second(4,6);
```

Comment: You probably mean `unless(wantarray)`. ;)  Anyway +1. :) It works nicely, and I can even call the `caller(1)` to get more informations. However, I will wait a bit with the accept - i'm looking for a solution (if possible) using the `DB` package (especially the @DB::args and the `sub` call. It is much easier to force the `perl -d:SomeMyTracer` as edit all scripts.

Comment: @kobame, you are right, he means 'unless', I edited it for completeness.